# Why does my program crash when I restart it after removal from the recent-apps bar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, multitasking

I'm a bit of a programming newbie so sorry if this shows my ignorance...

Situation 1:

- My program is running in the simulator. I press the home button, and then my program's icon again, and it goes back to exactly where it was. This much is obvious - it's been frozen by the iPhone's multitasking system.

Situation 2:

- My program is running in the simulator. I press the home button, but this time I then double-click the program and delete it from the recent-apps bar. Then I press the program's icon to start it again.

In situation 2, I expect my program just to load from the beginning, but instead, it goes back to the page it was 'frozen' on, briefly, before crashing.

Why is this?

**EDIT** - here is the backtrace of the crash. I've done it with a completely clean install of my app with no data, from the first screen you see, to keep variables to a minimum:

```
#0  0x96dc009a in mach_msg_trap ()
#1  0x96dc0807 in mach_msg ()
#2  0x0111cd86 in __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort ()
#3  0x01079e74 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#4  0x01079840 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#5  0x01079761 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#6  0x01c821c4 in GSEventRunModal ()
#7  0x01c82289 in GSEventRun ()
#8  0x001c4c93 in UIApplicationMain ()
#9  0x00002429 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff050) at main.m:14
```

Comment: Where does it crash, in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`?  Let's get a backtrace here.

Comment: Can't really tell much from that backtrace.  One thought that occurs to me: are you running through the Xcode debugger?  It could be that when you kill the app, the debugger sort of prevents the process from being completely destroyed, causing the crash on the subsequent launch.  Does it work correctly if you initially launch the app from the simulator instead of via Xcode's debugger?

Comment: gdb halts on that line when you kill the app in the background while Xcode is attached to the app. As Daniel said above, try launching the app from the simulator instead of using Build and Run in Xcode.

Comment: @Daniel I think you might be right... if I load the iPhone simulator without XCode running, then I don't get the crash. Do you think this is just an SDK foible, and that my program is fine? (BTW, you might copy your comment to an answer so I can upvote you).

Comment: @Ric: This sort of artifact happens when you combine debugging with multitasking launch/run/launch/run/etc. You get stale debugger sessions that mess with the process stuff on iOS. If you don't see this problem on device/simulator with no debugger attached, then you're fine. In general, I'd describe killing an app from the iOS UI without terminating it in the debugger as an "unsupported configuration" (you get what you get).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copied from comment because this theory appears to have been correct: Are you running through the Xcode debugger? It could be that when you kill the app, the debugger sort of prevents the process from being completely destroyed, causing the crash on the subsequent launch. Apparently it work correctly if you initially launch the app from the simulator instead of via Xcode's debugger.

Answer (score 1):

When your app is terminated from the App Switcher, it calls your app delegate's `applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application` method. Here you should save all application state–all of the memory your app uses will be released. What's likely happening is either that something in your `applicationDidEnterBackground:` method is crashing or something in the mass deallocating of your object model is causing a crash.

**edit:**

I just reread your question and saw that it's crashing on *relaunch*. Sorry. You should also check `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` for a crash, as that is called when your app first starts. Although since you're seeing the last screen before the app was closed, the crash still seems like it may be tied to terminatation.

How to get a backtrace:

If you run the code in the simulator with debugging on in Xcode and reproduce this crash, you should be able to discover which line is crashing. When the debugger picks up on the crash and gdb turns on (you should see a `(gdb)` prompt in Xcode), type `bt` and press enter to see the backtrace of the crash. Paste it here.

[See the docs of UIApplicationDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for more info on `applicationWillTerminate:`.

Comment: Just want to point out that the first sentence in this answer is incorrect: `applicationWillTerminate:` will _not_ be called when your app gets terminated while in the background.  Instead, your app gets killed with no further ado.  That's why you need to make sure in `application:didEnterBackground:` that you save any persistent data.

Comment: @Daniel- you're right, my mistake. Updated answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. For some reason the simulator prevents us to kill the app we are testing.
One thing I did for testing was to create a dummy project to 
If you launch the simulator from another dummy project.
Then I could open/close/kill test notifications, etc in my original project.

Answer (score 1):

Unplug the phone, yes. GDB, the debugger, is the cause of this issue.